# Closing focused program from the command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Is there a way to close a program that's currently in focus from the command line?

I’m running a voice control program that executes commands in the background. The only way I know to do it is with the `taskkill` command, which requires me to put in a specific process name. I want it to kill whatever process is currently in focus, so if Firefox is focused, it kills that and if notepad is focused, it kills that.

I'm using win 10 in case that's relevant.

Comment: You can't do that using built-in Windows utilities, but you can do that with programs such as AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there’s no linkage between the command environment and the GUI. When you use `taskkill` to kill an application, it’s acting on the *process*, not the window. This is an important distinction because by killing a process, you’re doing it forcefully; the same as if it has crashed. This probably isn’t what you want to be doing most of the time.

Normally, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will close the currently focused window (or <kbd>Esc</kbd> if it’s a dialog box).  This shortcut is equivalent to choosing File -> Quit from the menu bar or clicking the Close button on the title bar.

To do it from a command prompt, you’d need a script that can identify the active window and send it keystrokes. This can be done with PowerShell. The Windows Script Host (i.e. VBScript or JavaScript) can do it too.  But it would require some programming skills. Programs like AutoHotKey or KiXtart are another option.

Basically, you’d be calling the script from the command line via your voice control program.

Note that the application will do its normal closing routine (e.g. prompting you to save your work, etc), so it’s not a forced termination the way `taskkill` would do it.

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, I'm using a program to execute windows shell commands in the background and I don't think you can use ALT+F4 in windows shell, can you?

Comment: @Acituanbus; When you say ‘Windows shell’, what are you referring to? The command prompt? And what program are you using to execute commands in the background?

Comment: Yes, the command promp. It's called LINKS Mark 2, it's a just-for-fun voice-controlled program

Comment: @Acituanbus; I edited your question and updated my answer to reflect that information. Basically, you’ll need some scripting skills. There’s no silver bullet for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a way to close any program that's currently in focus via the Windows Shell?

That's not possible because in order to type any command in the windows shell you must switch focus to the shell.

The previously focused program (window) will lose focus.

As far as I know there is no windows shell command that will close the **previously** focused program.

Comment: I'm using a program that executes shell commands in the background and want it to kill the current window in focus, so it should be possible

Answer (score -1):

**AutoIt** can do it. Just several commands.
Look for:

```
$pid=WinGetProcess([ACTIVE])
ProcessClose($pid)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).